# Self join producing wrong results -SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables.

1. Client_packet:

[image]

2. Programs:

[image]

Out of these 2 tables, I want to find the packet ID and parent packet ID.

Desired result:

[image]

Rextester link:  https://rextester.com/GXQ46948 - My trial code is in this link.

Trial code:

```
select pd.CID, pd.packet_id,pd2.packet_id,pd.packet_status
from #package_details pd
join #Program p on p.PID = pd.program_id
join #package_details pd2 on pd.CID = pd2.CID and pd2.program_id=p.parent_prog_id  --parent episode
join #Program p2 on p2.PID=pd2.program_id
```

This self join is producing wrong result. Any help?!

Comment: I don't understand what rules you are applying. What makes you say that packet 21 is parent packet to packet 20? Why isn't it packet 16? Because a parent packet must have the same status as a child packet? Or is there some other reason? And what to do, if we find several parent packets to a packet? And what if a parent program has itself a parent program? Please be more elaborate as to these relations.

Comment: That's the problem. I have only this much of info on the tables. Bad data structure. So there is nothing to determine which child packet has which parent packet..like no flag kind of.

Comment: That's always going to be an issue then... Ignoring any potential issues with things like parent ID loops, there's no _real_ way to match parents and children. You're assuming 20 and 21 are connected and 15 and 16 are connected. Is that because the packet_status matches? Because the IDs are sequential? You kind of need to have some sort of rule you want to base it on or you're not going to get the results you desire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more clause in your join to get your expected output. Since ZLK and Ben already pointed out the join issues, you can make sure that it is within the same status, and you can get your output in this way.

```
 select pd.CID, pd.packet_id,pd2.packet_id as ParentpacketID,pd.packet_status from   
 #package_details pd
 join #Program p on p.PID = pd.program_id
 join #package_details pd2 on pd.CID = pd2.CID and  pd2.program_id=p.parent_prog_id 
 and pd2.packet_status = pd.packet_status  
 join #Program p2 on p2.PID=pd2.program_id  --not sure if you need this join as you are not selecting anything from this, and the output remains same without this join too.
```

Output:

```
 CID    packet_id   ParentpacketID  packet_status
 1001   20            21                 OPEN
 1001   15            16                 CLOSED
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your join is wrong:

```
select pd.CID, pd.packet_id,pd2.packet_id,pd.packet_status
from #package_details pd
join #Program p on p.PID = pd.program_id
-- I think the wrong part of code was here as you should not link per ID
join #package_details pd2 on pd2.program_id=p.parent_prog_id  --parent episode
join #Program p2 on p2.PID=pd2.program_id
```